# I want to give access to users of their own dropbox from my java web app. How can I do that?

Tags: java, file-upload, dropbox, dropbox-api

Right now I've created an app on dropbox, I called its APIs and made an Authentication Demo. I generated Key and Secret from the dropbox site for my app. Here I've to give 'key' and 'secret' to the program. Now what I've to do is to give access to the user of their own dropbox account. Guide me to do this. Thanks.

I took reference of [1]: http://ytotare.blogspot.in/2013/05/integration-with-dropbox-including.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To integrate with Dropbox in a Java app, the official Java SDK for the Dropbox API is recommended:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/java

Following the tutorial is a good way to get started:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/java

The full documentation can be found here:

http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v1.7.x/

To let users connect to their own accounts, you have to implement the OAuth app authorization flow. The tutorial linked above shows a simple version of it using `DbxWebAuthNoRedirect`. Actual web apps, for example, will want to use `DbxWebAuth` instead to streamline the process. The "web-file-browser" sample app included with the SDK is a good example to see this.